# Visual Basic 6 on Win7 64bit: Will developed program run on 32-bit Win OS?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, vb6, 32bit-64bit

I am using the Visual Basic 6 IDE on a machine that runs on a 64bit Windows 7 OS.
Codejock Xtreme SuitePro 15 is also used for interface stuff.

Users of the program being developed are using 32bit Windows, probably XP.

Could the program (developed on 64bit) work fine on the target environment?

Thanks.

EDIT: OS is Windows 7, updated/upgraded to SP1.

Comment: If using `ADO` there is a breaking change in Win7 SP1 (both x86 & x64) -- read this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/3a4ce946-effa-4f77-98a6-34f11c6b5a13?prof=required

Comment: @wqw Thank you for this. I guess I've more problems than I thought. With the program almost done, this is a real headache. More research on workarounds need to be done.

Answer (score 11):

YES. There's no such thing as 64-bit VB6 application.

Comment: Thanks sir @JosephH.

Have you got any insight on the use of Codejock Software though?

Comment: @juro Just ask these Codejock people whether they support XP

Comment: @Deanna We can always hope though that's pretty thin anymore.  I console myself with the fact that 64-bits doesn't really buy you anywhere near as much as the move from 16 to 32-bit did though.

Comment: @MarkJ My concern was the use of Codejock in a 64bit development environment for a program that's to be used in a 32bit environment, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Codejock provide both 32 and 64 bit versions of their controls - but you won't be able to use the 64bit version with VB6 - it is 32Bit only.

Comment: Thank you.

I'd assume you have experience with this, so if I may, I'd like to ask if copying the dll files of the Codejock controls to the project directory and reference from there in the vb6 project's components would be more beneficial than just referencing to them from their (Codejock Software's) installation directory on the dev machine?

Comment: That means everything else on the system will then use them from your project dir. Registered files should go in the location the author specifies.

Comment: Well the codejock controls are ocx's not dll's. It doesn't really matter where these are located but to avoid confusion you should only have one set on each machine - tradition says these should be in %WINDOWS%\System32

Answer (score 1):

You should be programming your product on a system that is as close as possible to your target system.

You should also be testing your product on all intended systems.

The issue therefore becomes merely something that you find out through testing.  It is not a theoretical question and is not something open to debate.

You are just a humble programmer who is not to know what the powers that be at Microsoft are doing with their systems.  Do thorough testing and leave it at that.  This is the approach taken by large software development enterprises.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I wanted to show that Codejock has built in support for backward compatibility between versions of MFC.

The options are available inside the Suite Pro or Toolkit Pro installers, and allow for x86 or x64 architecture.

[image]