# VB6 application on a 64bit machine

Tags: windows, vb6, 64-bit

I'm maintaining an old VB6 application, that uses some Sheridan 3D controls (SSPanel and SSTab, found in threed32.ocx and tabctl32.ocx).

Will this application work on a 64-bit machine (I guess the 32 in threed32 comes from the bit number?)

If not, what can I do to make it work?

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177555/visual-basic-6-on-win7-64bit-will-developed-program-run-on-32-bit-win-os)

Comment: the vb5 cd contains instructions to add the ocx's to the registry. They are located under VB5.0\Tools\Controls there is a readme file to install and register manually. the grid32.ocx and sheridan controls are part of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should run fine via [WoW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows).

EDIT: Since you've clarified that it's a 16-bit application<sup>1</sup>, if it's a LOB application that absolutely must run then you could try [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) for Windows 7 and later.

If you've got a copy of VB6 kicking around, try importing the project and compiling it at 32-bit.

Otherwise you might want to put the source code through the VB .NET project upgrade wizard and see how far you can get simply by targeting 32-bit.

<sup>1</sup> Are you sure it's VB6? The only references to 16-bit VB applications were from VB4

Comment: It is 16bit applications (from Windows 3.x, non-NT) that are not supported on 64bit Windows.

Comment: It seems unlikely that it is 16bit application - these controls are 32bit ones after all. Maybe just application installer is 16bit (old Installshield for example)?

Comment: Where'd they say it was a 64-bit app? VB6 is only ever 32-bit.

Comment: A VB6 app using threed32.ocx and tabctl32.ocx? It is a 32-bit app, definitely not a 16-bit app. And yes, it should run fine in WoW. Microsoft [still support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708) the VB6 runtime on 64-bit operating systems using Wow.

Comment: @MarkJ The issue is really that the *installer* is 16 bit, which is needed to license the controls so that you can compile your project with them.  I think you could manually apply the license through some registry hacking and I'm trying to look into that myself right now.  Would love it if someone else who's already done this would post their findings...